# Casteo de fechas almacenadas como Varchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Buenas, a todos nuevamente solicitando de su apoyo ya que tengo una duda sobre como ***Castear*** una fecha, que esta almacenada en la ***DB*** como ***Varchar*** con el siguiente formato ***20161105 0207***, necesito hacer un casteo de esta a tipo ***DateTime***, ***los primeros 8 dígitos*** corresponden a ***la fecha*** y ***los últimos cuatro a la hora y minuto***, para poder así generar una ***consulta que muestre registros en un rango de fechas***, he intentado las opciones que muestro en la parte inferior pero no me dan el resultado, si alguien sabe como hacerlo le voy a estar infinitamente agradecido.

```
select CAST(cor_fecha_transaccion as datetime) from Corresponsalias

select CONVERT(datetime,cor_fecha_transaccion,20)from Corresponsalias
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tristemente, para la versión de SQL Server que usas, creo que no tienes opción que de manipular la cadena usando una serie de `substring`s para transformarlo en un formato reconocido por la base datos para luego poder castearlo a un `datetime`.

Lo más sencillo sería modificar la cadena `20161105 0207` a `2016-11-05 02:07:00`, pera poder hacer un `cast(... as datetime)`:

```
declare @dtstring as varchar(14) = '20161105 0207';
select cast(substring(@dtstring,1,4) + '-' + 
            substring(@dtstring,5,2) + '-' +
            substring(@dtstring,7,2) + ' ' +
            substring(@dtstring,10,2) + ':' +
            substring(@dtstring,12,2) + ':00'
            as datetime)
```

[**Demostración en vivo**](http://rextester.com/YIIVF40427).

Aunque yo prefiero usar `cast`, puedes usar la misma técnica con `convert`:

```
declare @dtstring as varchar(14) = '20161105 0207';
select convert(datetime,
               substring(@dtstring,1,4) + '-' + 
               substring(@dtstring,5,2) + '-' +
               substring(@dtstring,7,2) + ' ' +
               substring(@dtstring,10,2) + ':' +
               substring(@dtstring,12,2) + ':00',
               120)
```

[**Demostración en vivo**](http://rextester.com/TLKLE4784).

Aunque estas opciones resuelvan el problema con tu consulta, por favor, piensa seriamente en convertir el tipo del campo en tu tabla de `varchar` a `datetime`. No es correcto de usar `varchar` para guardar una fecha. No solo te causa este tipo de problemas, pero además, te impide usar índices en estas columna para mejorar el rendimiento.

Comment: Esta opción es la que me funciono, solo que me queda la duda de como aplicarla a un campo en una tabla que tiene miles de registros y los convierta.

Comment: @Alberto: No entiendo la duda. Simplemente reemplazas `@dtstring` por el nombre del campo. ¿Tu duda tiene que ver con el rendimiento o es otra cosa?

Comment: era eso no sabia donde sustituir pero ya quedo muchas gracias, saludos y buen día.

Answer (score 0):

Para transformar esa fecha en un datetime seria algo asi

```
SELECT convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF('31012016',3,0,'-'),6,0,'-'), 105)
```

Me parece dudoso trabajar tipos de datos incorrectos, cuando el motor de base de datos te proporciona el dato que corresponde, asi se te facilitan las consultas futuras que quieras hacer.

Comment: ¿Qué es `31012016`?

Comment: La fecha 31012016

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer uso de `STUFF` de esta forma, para agregar los **dos puntos** de la hora, además de agregar el `SET DATEFORMAT ymd`:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF('20161105 0207',12,0,':'))
```